# Reading binary and text from same file in Python

Tags: python, utf-8, io, binaryfiles

How does one read binary and text from the same file in Python? I know how to do each separately, and can imagine doing both very carefully, but not both with the built-in IO library directly.

So I have a file that has a format that has large chunks of UTF-8 text interspersed with binary data. The text does not have a length written before it or a special character like "\0" delineating it from the binary data, there is a large portion of text near the end when parsed means "we are coming to an end".

The optimal solution would be to have the built-in file reading classes have "read(n)" and "read_char(n)" methods, but alas they don't. I can't even open the file twice, once as text and once as binary, since the return value of tell() on the text one can't be used with the binary one in any meaningful way.

So my first idea would be to open the whole file as binary and when I reach a chunk of text, read it "character by character" until I realize that the text is ending and then go back to reading it as binary. However this means that I have to read byte-by-byte and do my own decoding of UTF-8 characters (do I need to read another byte for this character before doing something with it?). If it was a fixed-width character encoding I would just read that many bytes each time. In the end I would also like the universal line endings as supported by the Python text-readers, but that would be even more difficult to implement while reading byte-by-byte.

Another easier solution would be if I could ask the text file object its real offset in the file. That alone would solve all my problems.

Comment: Without knowing how the data is delimited there is no way to do this as the binary data values could potentially coincide with utf-8 values.

Comment: Think about it as an XML file (although its not) where `<some_tag_names>` indicates that there is switch to binary data. That tag could contain attributes though, and the tags aren't necessarily predefined (the file itself could say `some_tag_names` is a binary element). The transition to binary is unambiguous but difficult to do since its not like read until a particular character or read n bytes.

Comment: You can read n bytes..

Comment: What I meant is I cannot read n bytes and know that is the extent of the text data (which is commonly do for text strings embedded in binary files, they are prefixed with the length in bytes/characters).

Comment: You just need to do your own buffering and scan the buffer for the delimiter for the state you're in.

Comment: Which is basically what I am saying the question and hoping that there is some built in that doesn't involve me recreating the entire TextIOWrapper class with a few changes...

Comment: Why would someone have written an io stream for your arbitrary file format?

Comment: For the generic situation of text and binary data mixed? I don't know, maybe because nearly every non-pure text format mixes text and binary... I know that my situation is a bit unique with non-standard delineations, but I have seen several formats like that. Basically, if Python would have added one method like `true_tell()` there would be no problem. If there was a way to get that information, which is a fairly generic situation, that would be a great answer. I am not asking how to read my format, I am asking how to do binary and text at the same time...

Comment: "So I have a file that has a format that has large chunks of UTF-8 text interspersed with binary data." Don't do that. On any platform. You wind up with a file that is neither UTF nor binary.

Comment: I am not the designer of the format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way might be to use [Hachoir](http://hachoir3.readthedocs.org/) to define a file parsing protocol.

The simple alternative is to open the file in binary mode and manually initialise a buffer and text wrapper around it. You can then switch in and out of binary pretty neatly:

```
my_file = io.open("myfile.txt", "rb")
my_file_buffer = io.BufferedReader(my_file, buffer_size=1) # Not as performant but a larger buffer will "eat" into the binary data 
my_file_text_reader = io.TextIOWrapper(my_file_buffer, encoding="utf-8")
string_buffer = ""

while True:
    while "near the end" not in string_buffer:
        string_buffer += my_file_text_reader.read(1) # read one Unicode char at a time

    # binary data must be next. Where do we get the binary length from?
    print string_buffer
    data = my_file_buffer.read(3)

    print data
    string_buffer = ""
```

A quicker, less extensible way might be to use the approach you've suggested in your question by intelligently parsing the text portions, reading each UTF-8 sequence of bytes at a time. The following code (from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_a_file_character_by_character/UTF8#Python), seems to be a neat way to conservatively read UTF-8 bytes into characters from a binary file:

```
 def get_next_character(f):
     # note: assumes valid utf-8
     c = f.read(1)
     while c:
         while True:
             try:
                 yield c.decode('utf-8')
             except UnicodeDecodeError:
                 # we've encountered a multibyte character
                 # read another byte and try again
                 c += f.read(1)
             else:
                 # c was a valid char, and was yielded, continue
                 c = f.read(1)
                 break

# Usage:
with open("input.txt","rb") as f:
    my_unicode_str = ""
    for c in get_next_character(f):
        my_unicode_str += c
```

Comment: A more [glorious](http://www.victorianweb.org/authors/carroll/kern7.html) hack, it is hard to imagine

Comment: Yes, this does look promising. It doesn't support universal newlines, but I have already found a way around that (and in general wouldn't be possible without at least 1 character buffering). I like the design as a generator as well, then in the `for c in ...` loop I just break as necessary.

Comment: Hi, see my new edit, which may be even quicker by dropping in and out of text mode around a buffer

Comment: And a variation on the previous solution

Comment: Ok, last change. I've presented a simple option using a TextWrapper around a buffer. I've tested this using the following string: `'blah blah \xe2\x82\xacnear the end\xaa\xff\xf0more \xe2\x82\xacstuff near the end\xff'`

Comment: After playing with your different solutions, I went with #1. The files are by far more binary data than text (although in general the binary data is read in one large batch). Additionally, the binary data is read with numpy, which didn't play well with the other options.