# python codec readline fail when unicode mixed with binary

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, readline, python-unicode

[python 3.4]
There is a UTF-8 file mixed with Japanese and binary.
I tried to read lines with code as following:

```
line = None
linecount = 0
with codecs.open(destfile, 'r', 'utf-8') as fd:
    while True:
        try:
            line = fd.readline()
            linecount += 1
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            continue

        if not line:
            break;

    print(linecount)
```

Try to ignore lines with binary code but it stops at line with binary code.

How can I read the file correctly ignoring line with binary code

Comment: A sample of the file would help get you a better answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading binary and text from same file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659104/reading-binary-and-text-from-same-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

`readline` reads larger chunks, decodes and buffers. If you hit an invalid utf-8 character, you will loose multiple lines within that invalid chunk. To keep things complicated, even if you think some of the data is binary, it may look like valid utf-8 and decode without error. Further, there really isn't such a thing as "binary lines" because lines are simply sequences of bytes delimited by a `0A` byte or perhaps a `0D0A` sequence. But those are both binary numbers so whose to say they were meant to terminate a line as opposed to just being part of the binary data.

Bearing that in mind, you can get further by decoding after you break things out on newlines:

```
line = None
linecount = 0

for line in open(destfile, 'rb'):
    try:
        line = line.decode('utf-8')
        linecount += 1
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        pass
print(linecount)
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. Problem here is less lines are read. 1000 lines in the file but only 500 are gotten. It maybe caused by EOF in the binary code. How can I bypass it to reach the real EOF?

Comment: Loosing multiple lines with a single `UnicodeDecodeError` means fewer lines will be read. Of the 1000 lines, 500 were lost because they happened to be in read-ahead chunks that were discarded. There is no EOF character, its just the error you get if you read past the end of the file, so there is nothing to bypass. I'm surprised that my code didn't count the lines correctly, its intent was to do the decode after splitting out the lines so that extras would not be discarded.

Comment: @briantmali, post a sample file with desired output.